# bazel debian package as a dependency for my project

Tags: build, bazel, bazel-rules

I need to build my project with bazel and it uses libcap-dev as a dependency. how to use that inside bazel? I tried used the genrule to install it but i can't use sudo inside the cmd section. I don't want to rebuild the package inside my code but if there is no other option please tell me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using packages from apt is not the most "bazelist" way to do manage dependencies. It would depend a lot on how your `sources.list` is configured and would not be hermetic at all.

### Build time dependency

I guess you need headers files as build-time dependencies.

You can grab tarballs from https://packages.debian.org/sid/libcap-dev with https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/http#http_archive or directly use the source repository https://salsa.debian.org/debian/libcap2 with the https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/git#new_git_repository rule.

Then you can import the lib with https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_import

### Runtime dependency

It depends a lot on what you are building. If you intend to run your project through `bazel run` with dynamically linked lib you will have to include the `.so` files in the `cc_library` for the matching `cc_binary` to find them.

If you intend to build a debian package that can be distributed you will have to add libcap as a dependency of this package.

### Example

> helpers.bzl

```
def _impl(repository_ctx):
    repository_ctx.download_and_extract(repository_ctx.attr.url, sha256=repository_ctx.attr.sha256)
    repository_ctx.extract("data.tar.xz", rename_files={"./usr/include/sys/capability.h":"./sys/capability.h"}) # Maybe use glob for archive extension
    repository_ctx.symlink(repository_ctx.attr.build_file, "BUILD")

deb_package = repository_rule(
    implementation=_impl,
    attrs={
        "url": attr.string(mandatory=True),
        "sha256": attr.string(mandatory=True),
        "build_file": attr.label(mandatory=True),
    },
)
```

> WORKSPACE

```
load("@//:helpers.bzl", "deb_package")

deb_package(
    name = "libcap2-dev",
    url = "http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap-dev_2.66-4_amd64.deb",
    sha256 = "da67132dba6eb1c452b999d9ac77c10ce4a5ad230ccbde1312868744b149f879",
    build_file = "@//:libcap2-dev.BUILD",
)
```

> libcap2-dev.BUILD

```
cc_import(
    name = "lib",
    hdrs = ["sys/capability.h"],
    shared_library = "usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so",
    static_library = "usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.a",
    visibility = [
        "//visibility:public"
    ]
)
```

> example.cc

```
#include "sys/capability.h"

int main(void)
{
        cap_t cap;
        cap = cap_get_proc();

        return 0;
}
```

> BUILD

```
cc_binary(
    name = "example_libcap2",
    srcs = [
        "example.cc",
    ],
    deps = ["@libcap2-dev//:lib"],
)
```

Comment: cc_import is used with precompiled libraries. when i pull a library from git is it precompiled?!!

Comment: And can you please provide a full example as i am really stuck

Comment: I added an example :)